# Why im getting error on QuerySnapShot firestore flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to create a social app with flutter & firestore.
when i try to run my app on emulator im getting error like this.
**Class 'QuerySnapshot' has no instance getter 'documents'.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: documents**

How to solve this error? im new for flutter & firebase. I can feel that, my coding cant read documents from cloud firestore. but i dont know how to clear it.

**My code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mysuroo_in/widgets/indicators.dart';

typedef ItemBuilder<T> = Widget Function(
  BuildContext context,
  DocumentSnapshot doc,
);

class StreamBuilderWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  final Stream<dynamic> stream;
  final ItemBuilder<DocumentSnapshot> itemBuilder;
  final Axis scrollDirection;
  final bool shrinkWrap;
  final ScrollPhysics physics;
  final EdgeInsets padding;

  const StreamBuilderWrapper({
    Key key,
    @required this.stream,
    @required this.itemBuilder,
    this.scrollDirection = Axis.vertical,
    this.shrinkWrap = false,
    this.physics = const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0, left: 2.0),
  }) : super(key: key);


//Got error here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var list = snapshot.data.documents.toList();
          return list.length == 0
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60.0,
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text('No Posts'),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : ListView.builder(
                  padding: padding,
                  scrollDirection: scrollDirection,
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  shrinkWrap: shrinkWrap,
                  physics: physics,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return itemBuilder(context, list[index]);
                  },
                );
        } else {
          return circularProgress(context);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/054EP.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using new firestore library in flutter then you have to use,

```
var list = snapshot.data.docs.toList()
```

instead of using

```
var list = snapshot.data.documents.toList();
```

inside your stream builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 var list = snapshot.data['documents'].toList();
```

because data argument is a map

or if it doesn't work with you use this

```
var list = snapshot.data()['documents'].toList();
```

Comment: Sorry to say that, getting same error if I used ur two solutions. But anyways Thank you bro..

Answer (score 0):

From the new firebase version you can call

```
docs() instead of documents()
```

Before

```
var list = snapshot.data.documents.toList();
```

After

```
QuerySnapshot snap = snapshot.data;
var list = snap.docs;
//now you will have list of documents in the list
```